# Java window not setting background color?

Tags: java, swing, awt

This is probably a really stupid error but iv'e just started learning the .awt package. I followed a tutorial to the letter, in the video his window's background is red, there are no errors in my code yet it won't change the background color.
Thanks for any help!

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setVisible(true);
f.setSize(350,350);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setTitle("Window");
f.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }

}
```

Comment: not sure - but maybe move the setVisible to the end - then you get the current settings without having to refresh in some way.

Comment: Not doing it i'm afraid! Here's the video + my applet in case im going color blind! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uK2BscDZyNo&feature=relmfu    http://i.imgur.com/LQMOL.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) `JFrame` can't do that, you have to change `Color` for content pane e.g.

```
JFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(myColor)
```

2) You need to wrap GUI related code (in `main` method) to the `invokeLater`

For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI {

    public GUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Test Background");
        frame.setLocation(200, 100);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                GUI gUI = new GUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
f.setBackground(Color.RED);
```

call

```
f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
```

The content pane is what is displayed.

As a side note, here's a `JFrame` tip: you can call `f.add(child)` and the child will be added to the content pane for you.

Comment: Thanks...I need to learn to answer faster...and to ignore my coworkers when I'm answering :)