# Java swing custom background

Tags: java, swing, background

I have a JFrame on which I have some panels, each containing different items. How can I set the frame background ? I mean, if I set only the background, without adding the items, the background is the one I wanted, but if I add the items, the background is clear. Likewise, if I first set the background of one panel and then insert some objects into it, the item does not appear on the frame, the frame is colored with the background I chose. Could you show me the easiest way to set a background color to a panel/frame that already has items? Thanks. I would like to set a custom bacground color. If the only way is to set a background Image, I will go for that...

EDIT : I want a single background color, not more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had made a sample program for you, do let me know, if you want something other than this. I had done it both ways, you can set a new Color to the Background without any Item on the JPanel by pressing the JButton, or you can first add Item to the JPanel and then change the Background Color, this is working fine. Seems like your question is a bit unclear as to what is expected, and what actually is happening. Do let me know, if you want something else, other than this.

Moreover, as you add Items to the already displayed JPanel, always revalidate() and repaint() your JPanel after that, for changes to take effect.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AddItemOrColor extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton modifyItemButton;
    private JButton modifyColorButton;
    private ActionListener action;
    private int count = 0;
    private Color[] color = { 
                                Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GRAY,
                                Color.WHITE, Color.CYAN, Color.PINK,                                                                                                                                     
                                Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.ORANGE, Color.MAGENTA
                            };

    public AddItemOrColor()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);

        contentPane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 3, 3));
        //contentPane.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        modifyItemButton = new JButton("MODIFY CONTENT");
        modifyColorButton = new JButton("MODIFY COLOR");

        action = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                JButton button = (JButton) ae.getSource();

                if (count == 9)
                    count = 0;

                if (button == modifyItemButton)
                {
                    contentPane.add(new JLabel("LABEL " + count));                  
                }
                else if (button == modifyColorButton)
                {
                    contentPane.setBackground(color[count]);
                }

                contentPane.revalidate();
                contentPane.repaint();
                count++;
            }
        };

        modifyItemButton.addActionListener(action);
        modifyColorButton.addActionListener(action);

        add(modifyColorButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(modifyItemButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new AddItemOrColor();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that one of the easiest thing to change the background color of the parent frame and all children Jpanel could be set the background color of the Jframe and then iterate over all the child Jpanel and set the background also to them :

```
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(somecolor);
for(JComponent c : frame.getComponents()) {
if(c instanceof JPanel) {
c.setBackground(somecolor);
}
}
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer, for JFrame only [ContentPane can have a Color](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9383680/714968)

Comment: @Theo. please can you be a little bit concrete, are you meaning to set one Color and this Color will be used everywhere???,

Answer (score 1):

You should call setOpaque(false) on the panels which contain your items.